# Multi id selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-3

```
$('body').append($('#add-done-modal, #add-failed-modal', data));
```

This code should append the `div` with `id` `add-done-modal` and `add-failed-modal` to `body`. Those `div` are served in `data` among other stuff. I'm sure the `html` in `data` is perfectly fine and intended.
The code never find the `id`. I'm using jQuery 3.3.1.
I know classes are a solution, but would be rather unwieldy due to various modal that could be or not chosen depending on the client calling.

EDIT: A simple `$('#add-done-modal', data)` returns an empty jQuery object. I am, once again, sure `#add-done-modal` is in `data`.

EDIT: This function is called by a `click`event:

```
function popup(url, name) {
  $.get(url, (data) => {
    $('#loading-modal .modal-body').html($('#product', data));
    // Can't find '#add-done-modal' nor '#add-failed-modal'
    let x = $('#add-done-modal', data);
    x = $('#add-failed-modal', data);
    $('body').append($('#add-done-modal, #add-failed-modal', data));
    // Initialize jQuery-UI or Bootstrap stuff loaded above here. Working.
  });

  $('#loading-modal .modal-header .modal-title').html(name);
  $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
}
```

Here is the content returned by the AJAX call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <!-- Head stuff -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="all">
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="col-8 col-lg-9">
              <form action="/updatelocale/" method="POST">
                <select class="bs-select" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                  <!-- Locale options, can be disregarded -->
                </select>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col justify-content-md-end">
              <div class="row">
                <!-- Login and some buttons, not used -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <header class="nav-holder make-sticky">
        <div id="navbar" role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <!-- A pretty navbar -->
        </div>
      </header>
      <div id="heading-breadcrumbs">
        <!-- Cute breadcrumbs -->
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <!-- Product, loading this from data works -->
        <div id="product" class="container">
          <div id="productMain" class="row">
            <!-- Stuff inside #product -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <!-- Pretty footer -->
      </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal #add-done-modal -->
    <div id="add-done-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-done-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
      <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 id="add-done-modalLabel" class="modal-title">cart.add.done</h4>
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">cart.add.done.long</div>
          <div class="modal-footer"><button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">modal.close</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal #add-failed-modal -->
    <div id="add-failed-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-failed-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
      <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 id="add-failed-modalLabel" class="modal-title">cart.add.failed</h4>
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">cart.add.failed.long</div>
          <div class="modal-footer"><button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">modal.close</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="login-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
      <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- I don't care about this modal -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hng8n57g/) with some tests. After rendering the document to the DOM, `$('#add-done-modal, #add-failed-modal')` and `$('#add-done-modal')` find the modals, before it doesn't.
In this second [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eprc5uwv/2/) with static HTML, I checked if the modals were found, they were.

Is there any limit to jQuery context length for HTML strings?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked the result of `$('#add-done-modal, #add-failed-modal', data)`?

Comment: Do note that `data` has to be an `Element` or a jQuery object... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: @Phil Yes I did. "The code never find the `id`." `$('#add-done-modal, #add-failed-modal')` never find anything but the `div` are in `data`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No, it doesn't. It can also be an html string not in the `document`.

Comment: @AlexandreParent where exactly does it say it can be an HTML string? The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) clearly states _"A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context"_ Perhaps you should try `let context = $(data)` and use that

Comment: @Phil My experience... I do load other stuff from `data`.
If you wish I can post the whole function.

Comment: @AlexandreParent you know what, you're right ~ https://jsfiddle.net/tm2w7g6a/1/. I think we're going to have to see what's in `data`

Comment: @Phil Coming right up... Just editing the generated HTML for brevity.

Comment: @AlexandreParent after you edit it, make sure you still see the same issue :)

Comment: @Phil I just removed uneeded information. Unless jQuery cannot parse an HTML string 9663 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with the HTML string properly, I'd suggest parsing it into a document, eg

```
const domParser = new DOMParser()
const doc = domParser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html')
```

then use `doc` in your jQuery selectors, eg

```
$('#add-done-modal', doc)
```

---

When jQuery encounters a context, it simply converts the expression to...

```
jQuery(context).find(selector)
```

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.3.1/src/core/init.js#L99

The issue here is that jQuery parses entire documents into a jQuery object containing the top-level elements under `<body>`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

> But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML

For example, taking your HTML as a string...

```
$(html)
```

gives me a jQuery object with 15 elements, mostly empty text and some comment nodes but including

```
#3  <div id="all">...</div>
#7  <div id="add-done-modal"...>...</div>
#11 <div id="add-failed-modal"...>...</div>
#13 <div id="login-modal"...>...</div>
```

Using this object as a selector *context*, you can find elements that are children of those 5 but not those elements themselves. This is why you can find `#product` for example.

Comment: I didn't know you could create in-memory `document`... Considering jQuery finds the selectors once the HTML is parsed, it may well be the solution.

Comment: @AlexandreParent yeah, I had a feeling it wouldn't. It seems odd though.

Comment: Second solution works! May I suggest you remove first solution? And your guess is false because it does works for elements much higher in the string.

Comment: Nah, I'll leave it. Like I said, it _should_ work :)

Comment: I don't see why? I'm almost certain AJAX only use datatype to validate headers.

Comment: @AlexandreParent Sometimes it uses it to parse / format the `data` passed to the `success` callback (eg `'json'`). For `'html'` though (and I've only just read this in the doco), the result is an HTML string. Why jQuery is unable to use that string as a context, I'm not sure but `$(data)` doesn't result in anything useful either which was the basis for my _"guess"_ above

Comment: @AlexandreParent I've update my answer with some more info that I think describes what's going on